# Can WPF Ribbon Control be used in Visual studio 2008 using c#, and how it can be used

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008

I want to use WPF Ribbon control in C# .Net, in Desktop Application.Is it feasible to use,just for UI Design.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [WPF Ribbon control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799534.aspx) requires .NET 4.0. VS 2008 doesn't support .NET 4.0. So the answer to your question is simple: **no**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! The Ribbon is supported for .NET version 3.5 and VS 2008.

Check out [this tutorial](http://www.uxpassion.com/blog/old-blog/how-to-use-add-ribbon-to-wpf-applications).

Note: Part 3 of the tutorial is outdated. You don't use RibbonCommands anymore, it now uses ICommands like everything else in WPF.

(Also the part about how you acquire the installer may be outdated. But it is easy to get.)

So far, WPF is great! : )